# grep for html what's wrong?

Tags: html, regex, wget

```
<a href=\"\/foo\/.*"\s>.*?<\/a>
to grep
    <a href="/foo/thong" >Good</a><a href="/foo/thing" >Bad</a>
```

gives the whole line.
What if I wanted to get the two separated matches? (all single matches between  and )

Comment: [Obligatory](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the non-greedy option inside the `href` argument as well.

```
preg_match_all('#<a href="/foo/.*?" >.*?</a>#', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo '<a href="/foo/thong" >Good</a><a href="/foo/thing" >Bad</a>' |
sed 's/<a href=\"\/foo\/\([^\"]*\)\"\s>[^<]*<\/a>/\1\n/g'
```